# PHP foreach how to access variable outside loop

Tags: php, twitter, foreach

I have this code to tap into a twitter feed...

```
// Output tweets
  $json = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=false&screen_name=*********&count=100", true);
  $decode = json_decode($json, true);

  $count = count($decode); //counting the number of status
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    //echo $decode[$i]["text"]."<br><br>";
    $text = $decode[$i]["text"]." ";
    echo $text;
  }
```

I want to access $text in another function. Can this be done?

Comment: Your question is about `foreach`. I don't see any `foreach` statement in you code.

Comment: Did you write this code ? Your request is simpler ....

Comment: Why not return an array of strings?

Comment: Access it in what way?  Within the loop you can call a function and pass it the value.  Or if the variable is in scope outside of the loop then code outside the loop can refer to either its pre-loop value or its post-loop value.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry. Working on multiple pieces of code and mistakenly put in foreach. I was trying to accomplish combining all tweets and going though the string to check for certain words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just have an array and insert it on each run of the loop and then echo it out or return it.

```
 $arr = array();
 for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
   $text = $decode[$i]['text'];
   $arr[] = $text;
   echo $text . " ";
 }

 var_dump($arr);
```